# Having trouble maintaining order of Session headers when making a request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I was suggested by a forum-user that in order to avoid detection I need to maintain 
same order of headers as my browser.
I have looked at the suggestion here:

[Python HTTP request with controlled ordering of HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239952/python-http-request-with-controlled-ordering-of-http-headers)

However, despite attempting the suggestions, the order is changing. 
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong (notice that cookie ends up at the end):

```
import requests
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from collections import OrderedDict


BASE_URL = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/'
HEADERS = OrderedDict({'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Cookie': '',
            'Host': 'www.bloomberg.com',
            'Origin' : 'https://www.bloomberg.com',
            'Referer': 'https://www.bloomberg.com/',
             'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0',

           })




def latest_news():
        session = requests.Session()
        session.headers = HEADERS
##        session.headers['User-Agent'] = HEADERS['User-Agent']
##        session.headers['Referer'] = HEADERS['Referer']
##        #session.headers['Origin'] = HEADERS['Origin']
##        session.headers['Host'] =   HEADERS['Host'] 

        page = session.get(BASE_URL, allow_redirects = True)
        print(page.url)
        print(page.request.headers)
        print(page.history)
        page.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        print(soup)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    latest_news()
```

OUTPUT:

```
 https://www.bloomberg.com/tosv2.html?vid=&uuid=e5737f50-3975-11ea-b7bd-97b9265w12w5&url=Lw==


#Request Headers      

{'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
     'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
     'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
    'Host': 'www.bloomberg.com', 
    'Origin': 'https://www.bloomberg.com', 
    'Referer': 'https://www.bloomberg.com/',
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:64.0)
     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0', 
    'Cookie': '_pxhd=4c7cs06d7c42as40601e7d338a1084ca96e4ee91dfa42bd2368e86fec4e66bcd1:e573a66d0-397x5-11ea-b7bd-97b9265412f5'}


[<Response [307]>]

<h1 class="logo">Bloomberg</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **General Answer** i wrote because i had a similar problem, your problem might be that the web-server asks you to add those cookies to your further requests. You've set your cookies to `''`, so they are discarded and your new cookies appended to the end of the headers as per the servers request.
What if we just use get():

```py
import requests
import logging
import http.client as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

#init logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

requests.get("http://google.com", allow_redirects=False)
```

Here I've enabled logging so you see the requests as they're being made(logging code not shown in future examples). This yields the output:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): google.com:80
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.21.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n'
...
```

As you see, requests initiates some headers even when we haven't told it to. Now what happens if we pass some headers to it in some format we want?

```py
import requests
headers = { 
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
}
requests.get("http://google.com", headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

Here we expect "user-agent" to show up at the end of our request, however the output shows otherwise:

```
 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): google.com:80
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\naccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\naccept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nupgrade-insecure-requests: 1\r\n\r\n'
...
```

The "user-agent" shows up in the middle! What gives? Lets take a look at some source code from the library.

---

```py
def __init__(self):

        #: A case-insensitive dictionary of headers to be sent on each
        #: :class:`Request <Request>` sent from this
        #: :class:`Session <Session>`.
        self.headers = default_headers()
        ...
```

When we initiate a `Session`, the first thing it does is assign it default headers, and any additional headers provided by the user "indirectly"(through a function) will be appended to the default one.
This is a problem, as when you append two dicts(even OrderedDicts), the result retains the order of the original dict. We can see this in the above example where the "user-agent" attribute retained it's position of **second in the dict**.
This is the code for the appending process if you're interested:

```py
def merge_setting(request_setting, session_setting, dict_class=OrderedDict):
    """Determines appropriate setting for a given request, taking into account
    the explicit setting on that request, and the setting in the session. If a
    setting is a dictionary, they will be merged together using `dict_class`
    """

    if session_setting is None:
        return request_setting

    if request_setting is None:
        return session_setting

    # Bypass if not a dictionary (e.g. verify)
    if not (
            isinstance(session_setting, Mapping) and
            isinstance(request_setting, Mapping)
    ):
        return request_setting

    merged_setting = dict_class(to_key_val_list(session_setting))
    merged_setting.update(to_key_val_list(request_setting))

    # Remove keys that are set to None. Extract keys first to avoid altering
    # the dictionary during iteration.
    none_keys = [k for (k, v) in merged_setting.items() if v is None]
    for key in none_keys:
        del merged_setting[key]

    return merged_setting
```

---

## So what's the **fix**?

You'll have to override the default header completely. The way i can think to do this is to use a `Session`, and then replace the headers dict directly:

```py
session = requests.Session()
headers = { 
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"cookie": "Cookie: Something",
"upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
}
# session.cookies.add_cookie_header(session)
session.headers = headers
a = session.get("https://google.com/", allow_redirects=False)
```

Which yield the desired output, without the need for any `OrderedDict`

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): google.com:443
send: b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\naccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3\r\naccept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\naccept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\ncookie: Cookie: Something\r\nupgrade-insecure-requests: 1\r\nuser-agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n\r\n'
...
```

The above example proves that everything has stayed where it's supposed to be, even if you check `response.request.headers` everything should be in order(at least for me it is)
P.S: I haven't bothered to check if using an OrderedDict makes a difference here, but if you have any issues still, try using one instead.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will get a chance to go through it thoroughly in a couple of days, and will get back to you.

Comment: Okay, I think having the cookie set to empty was indeed the culprit. Thank you so much for your answer. I learned a couple of things (like debugging with requests).