# Requests adding own header attributes

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to make GET request with empty headers like this:

```
response = requests.get(url="https://www.google.com", headers={})
```

However requests adding default headers:

```
for key, value in response.request.headers.items():
    print(key + ": " + value)
```

```
User-Agent: python-requests/2.22.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
```

How to override it, and make dict truly empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers you pass are actually **appended** to existing defaults set by the library. You'll have to overwrite the dict directly if you want to change the headers' order or remove existing headers; for example by using a session:

```py
import requests
with requests.Session() as sess:
    sess.headers = {}
    response = sess.get(url="https://www.google.com")
    for key, value in response.request.headers.items():
        print(key + ": " + value)
```

For more about why this happens, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813647/7764138) post i made on the subject.