# Unable to extract and attribute value from webpage with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an attribute from but I must doing something wrong because I cant´t get it.

this is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pccomponentes.com/procesadores'

headers = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'es-ES, es;q=0.5'})

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
product = soup.find('div',class_ = 'col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4')
#print(product)

brand = product.find('a', attrs={'class': 'c-product-card__title-link cy-product-link'})['data-brand']
print(brand)
```

The target is to obtain "AMD".

Any help would be much appreciate.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The following implies that the Cloudflare have detected your requests to the website as an automated bot and subsequently denying you the access to the application.

[image]

Because of that you wont find any of your expected information but you may take a look at [Python's requests triggers Cloudflare's security while urllib does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684468/pythons-requests-triggers-cloudflares-security-while-urllib-does-not)

Comment: thanks hedgehog for your comments.

If I run the following code:

`
brand = product.header.h3.a
print(brand)
`
It returns the entire text including the data I want and when I scrape the price, product_name, etc, the code runs fine.